pest grammar failing to parse, I cannot work our why
Simplified grammar down to this
class_var = { kind ~ type ~ name ~ ";" }
kind      = { "static" | "field" }
type      = { "int" | "char" | "bool" | class_name }
class_name = {id}
name       =  { id }
id         =  { ASCII_ALPHA ~ ASCII_ALPHA* }
WHITESPACE = _{ " " | "\t" | "\n" }

trying to parse this (its a field declaration inside a class, it can either be a known type or a user defined class type)
field x f;

produces
 --> 1:10
  |
1 | field x f;
  |          ^---
  |
  = expected id

Works fine with
field int f;


This happens because ASCII_ALPHA matches 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z'. So while the first character of f1 is valid for id, the second is not. You likely want to use ASCII_ALPHANUMERIC instead for the remaining characters.
id = { ASCII_ALPHA ~ ASCII_ALPHANUMERIC* }

Additionally, you should consider making this rule atomic.
If you want to be extra complete, you might even want to consider using the XID_START and XID_CONTINUE Unicode character groups instead. They were created for this exact purpose and distinguish between all of the non-ascii characters.
id = @{ ( XID_START ~ XID_CONTINUE* ) | ( "_" ~ XID_CONTINUE+ ) }


TY, but this isnt the solution. I messed up the pasting into the question, now fixed. I also loaded into pests playground tester https://pest.rs/?g=N4Ig5gTghgtjURALhAYwDZQM5YPoDcEACAXiOCIGsBLAOwBMiA-IgFwE8AHAU2aNti8WAHRABuUUQC%2Bw2jQZFFSshVFZWUVtVSSAPkVEAzat3T1JM2hx5Ll5AyDqs9D1AAsEL0QCMA9r-QXDGw8ARheS2CcXDDeFWp6S1jbO3sE6Vl0lNSKAEEAZQBhAEli3FyAGQAFAAlcvgKSssra3IAqDNoAdRrigBUAUXyq3MKB0iJcVRAHIn1RYWFnGfmQRdoLEAAaR1pOAFdWZBBjU0YAD3OiQzEQKSA#editor

Aha - its the atomic that fixes it - ty.
